# Re-usable components and fixtures in Golang tests

Tags: postgresql, testing, go

I'm just getting started with Golang and writing my first test suite.

I have a background in Rails, which has fantastic support for testing tools (Rspec, Cucumber, etc..), so I'm approaching my golang tests with a similar mindset (not sure if that's the right or wrong thing to do)

I have a `User` data model (basically a struct) that reads records from a `users` table in postgres and stores an array of them. (Essentially a really simple version of what ActiveRecord does in the Rails world)

I'd like to write a test that checks if the routine correctly reads from the DB and builds the models.

1. In almost every test suite I'll be connecting to the DB so I have a helper named `establish_db_connection`. Where can I place this so that it's centrally available to all my tests?
2. Building off #1 - is there an equivalent of a `before` block or some setup/teardown method where I can establish a connection before every test?
3. Lastly, how do I handle fixtures? Right now before each test I call a `clear_db` function that resets all tables and inserts some static data rows. I'd love to move away from fixtures and use factories to build data as needed (very similar to `FactoryGirl` in Rails), but not sure how common that is in Golang.
4. Is the built-in `go test` framework the best approach, or are there better alternatives?

Comment: following up on pie's answer, you can make a `testfixtures` package if you need to use the helper across multiple packages' tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go is based on strong package management, meaning a namespace is treated as one single file. If `establish_db_connection` is used within a single test package, it can begin with a lowercase letter to signify a private instance and use it in the test file with the same package as the code being tested (Note that naming convention in Go is `establishDBConnection`). 
   However, most of the time, as in [data/sql](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/), you will want to obtain a DB connection once and keep that around until the test is finished (more like a factory and injection pattern).
2. There is none in the standard `testing` package. If you like BDD, [Goconvey](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey) use scopes to define fixtures and a `reset` function for teardown.
3. You can use factory and dependency injections in your testing. I think that's pretty idiomatic.
4. A few includes [Goconvey](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey), [Ginkgo](https://github.com/onsi/ginkgo) and [Testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) They all have pros and cons of their own. The first two often end up with too many nested scopes, but Goconvey has a great browser-based real-time testing server which can be used with Go standard testing.

Since there's no global variables/functions in Go, you might design your project in [interface-delegate pattern](https://medium.com/code-zen/go-interfaces-and-delegation-pattern-f962c138dc1e#.j3jzmb3r1) to help with importing functions cross packages and avoiding cyclic imports when dealing with cross-package testing.

```
mypackage

type DBOptions struct {
        Name, Credentials string
}

func aFunc(db *sql.DB) error {
        // do something
        return nil
}

func bFunc(db *sql.DB) int, error {
        // do something
        return 0, nil
}

func establishConn(opts *DBOptions) (*sql.DB, error) {
        db, err := sql.Open(opts.Name, opts.Credentials)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        return db, nil
}

func destroyConn(conn *sql.DB) {
        conn.Close()
}

// test file
mypackage 

import "testing"

var myOpt = &DBOptions{
        Name: "mysql", 
        Credentials: "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/hello",
}

var conn, _ = establishConn(myOpt)

func TestAFunc(t *testing.T) {
        err := aFunc(conn)

        if err != nil  {
                t.Error(err)
        }
}

func TestBFunc(t *testing.T) {
        err := aFunc(conn)

        if err != nil  {
                t.Error(err)
        }
}

// use `conn` in other tests ...

destroyConn(conn)
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the detailed explanation! You're right, it looks like all those testing libraries have their own pros/cons. I ran into the same issue when searching for an ORM for Postgres - there's a few, but nothing's really emerged as a robust standard unfortunately. With regards to your example - `myOpt` and `conn` in the testing file are not defined in any function, so I guess they get executed once (in the defined order) and are available to all tests?

Comment: Yes, the `conn` get created once then is available until `destroyConn` is called. You can create many `conn`'s as you want, including mocks and swap them in when testing.

Answer (score 2):

About test fixture library similar to FactoryGirl in Rails, There are some choices in go.

those two libraries got stars most.

- https://github.com/bluele/factory-go
- https://github.com/go-testfixtures/testfixtures

And I also implemented test-fixture library which is type-safe, DRY, and flexible compared to the above libraries!

- https://github.com/k-yomo/fixtory

Answer (score 1):

on fixtures: consider passing functions in your testcases:

```
package main

import "testing"

type testcase struct {
    scenario  string
    before    func(string)
    after     func()
    input     string
    expOutput string
}

var state = ""

func setup(s string) {
    state = s
}

func nilSetup(s string) {}

func reset() {
    state = ""
}

func execute(s string) string {
    return state
}

func TestSetupTeardown(t *testing.T) {
    tcs := []testcase{
        {
            scenario:  "blank output when initial state is wrong",
            before:    nilSetup,
            after:     reset,
            input:     "foo",
            expOutput: "",
        },
        {
            scenario:  "correct output when initial state is right",
            before:    setup,
            after:     reset,
            input:     "foo",
            expOutput: "foo",
        },
    }

    for _, tc := range tcs {
        tc.before(tc.input)
        if out := execute(tc.input); out != tc.expOutput {
            t.Fatal(tc.scenario)
        }
        tc.after()
    }
}
```

Comment: any thoughts @pieohpah?

Answer (score 0):

I built a tiny utility library to make it easy to create reusable fixtures to tests in go. Check out https://github.com/houqp/gtest to see if it solves your problem.

Here is a quick example on how to create a database transaction fixture for each test in a test group:

```golang
type TransactionFixture struct{}

// Construct can take other fixtures as input parameter as well
func (s TransactionFixture) Construct(t *testing.T, fixtures struct{}) (*sqlx.Tx, *sqlx.Tx) {
    tx := // create db transaction here
    return tx, tx
}

func (s TransactionFixture) Destruct(t *testing.T, tx *sqlx.Tx) {
    tx.Rollback()
}

func init() {
    // register and make fixture available to all tests
    gtest.MustRegisterFixture(
        "Transaction", &TransactionFixture{}, gtest.ScopeSubTest)
}

// begin of test definition
type SampleTests struct{}

func (s *SampleTests) Setup(t *testing.T)      {
    // you can create/initialize DB in this method
    // DB instance can also be implemented as a fixture and get injected into Transanction fixture.
}
func (s *SampleTests) Teardown(t *testing.T)   {
    // you can clean up all DB resources in this method
}
func (s *SampleTests) BeforeEach(t *testing.T) {}
func (s *SampleTests) AfterEach(t *testing.T)  {}

func (s *SampleTests) SubTestFoo(t *testing.T, fixtures struct {
    Tx sqlx.Tx `fixture:"Transaction"`
}) {
    // transaction is available as fixtures.Tx in this test
}

func TestSampleTests(t *testing.T) {
    gtest.RunSubTests(t, &SampleTests{})
}
```

See https://godoc.org/github.com/houqp/gtest and https://github.com/houqp/gtest/blob/master/example_test.go for more advanced and uptodate examples.